# What are the typical basis elements of a product topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

In section 19 of James Munkres' Topology, the author defines $\mathcal{S}_{\beta}=\left\{ \pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta}) \ | \ U_{\beta} \text{ open in} \ X_{\beta}\right\}$, and lets $\mathcal{S}$ denote the union of these collections: $\mathcal{S} = \bigcup_{\beta \in J}S_{\beta}$.

Then the author goes on to discuss the typical basis element in the basis $\mathscr{B}$ that $\mathcal{S}$ generates:

"the collection $\mathscr{B}$ consists of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{S}$. If we intersect elements belonging to the same one of the sets $\mathcal{S}_{\beta}$, we don't get anything new, because $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta})\cap\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(V_{\beta})=\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta}\cap V_{\beta})$. We get something new only when we intersect elements from different sets of $\mathcal{S}_{\beta}$. The typical element of the basis $\mathscr{B}$ can thus be described as follows: Let ${\beta}_1$, ..., ${\beta}_n$ be a finite set of distinct indices from the index set J, and let ${\beta}_i$ be an open set in $X_{{\beta}_i}$ for $i=1,..., n$. Then $B=\pi_{\beta_1}^{-1}(U_{\beta_1})\cap\pi_{\beta_2}^{-1}(U_{\beta_2})\cap\cdots\cap\pi_{\beta_n}^{-1}(U_{\beta_n})$ is the typical element of $\mathscr{B}$."

My confusion: $B=\pi_{\beta_1}^{-1}(U_{\beta_1})\cap\pi_{\beta_2}^{-1}(U_{\beta_2})\cap\cdots\cap\pi_{\beta_n}^{-1}(U_{\beta_n})$ is NOT an intersection of different $\mathcal{S}_{\beta_i}$'s. Instead,  $\mathcal{S}_{\beta_1}\cap\mathcal{S}_{\beta_2}\cap\cdots\cap\mathcal{S}_{\beta_n}$ is. What am I missing here?

Please help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: By definition $\pi_\beta^{-1}(U_\beta)$ is not in any of the $\mathcal{S}_\gamma$ for $ \gamma \neq \beta$. We take intersections of sets, not of families!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I appreciate your comment! And I believe you are correct unless when $U_\beta=X_\beta$.

Comment: or $\emptyset$….

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Actually, the empty set would not work.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma then I take that back - $\emptyset$ would indeed work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection $B$ is just the set of all $f$ in the product that obey the finitely many conditions imposed by being in $B=\pi_{\beta_1}^{-1}(U_{\beta_1})\cap\pi_{\beta_2}^{-1}(U_{\beta_2})\cap\cdots\cap\pi_{\beta_n}^{-1}(U_{\beta_n})$, i.e. $f \in \pi_{\beta_1}(U_{\beta_1})$ so $f(\beta_1) \in U_{\beta_1}$, and $f \in \pi_{\beta_2}(U_{\beta_2})$ so $f(\beta_2) \in U_{\beta_2}$ and so on till
$f \in \pi_{\beta_n}(U_{\beta_n})$ so $f(\beta_n) \in U_{\beta_n}$

We take intersections of the different **sets** in those families, not between the families themselves!

And the point Munkres makes is that we can combine two "open conditions" in the same coordinate to one "open condition" in that same coordinate.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! That sure is a different definition for intersections.

Comment: @Josh12913 it’s not really. The subbase is $\mathcal S$ and we take all finite intersections of members of it to get a base, just as Munkres explained in the theory part.

Comment: Indeed the open sets in the topology generated by the subbasis are all arbitrary unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{S}$. My problem with the author is regarding the definition of intersections - if we apply the general definition, then any basis element B in $\mathscr{B}$ would be an intersection of different $\mathcal{S}_{\beta_i}$'s, which are the members of $\mathcal{S}$; the elements in each $\pi_{\beta_i}^{-1}(U_{\beta_i})$ are NOT members of $\mathcal{S}$. Just like {1} is a member of P={{1,2,3},{1,2},{1}}, but 1 is not.

Comment: @Josh12913 you misunderstand $\mathcal S$ which equals $\{\pi_\beta^{-1}(U)\mid \beta \in J; U \subseteq X_\beta\text{ open }\}$

Comment: That is exactly where I was trapped - thank you so much!